# How to checkout a git worktree without specific files?

Tags: git, git-worktree

I want to use *git worktree* to manage many branches. I have the following problem. I have some scripts I don't want in my branches.

My command is `git worktree add src/new_branch`. To put `new_branches` in folder `src`.

I already tried `--no-checkout` but when I for example do:

```
cd src ; cd new_branch ; git checkout -b new_branch2 ; git checkout new_branch
```

…all files from `master` are back in the branch `new_branch` again.

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: This is Konfusing…

Comment: Files—whether scripts or otherwise—are not *in branches*. What is "in" a branch, in the sense of a [daglet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452) that is, are *commits*. Files are in *commits*. You check out a specific commit, whether or not you use a branch name, and you get all the files that are in that *commit*, which you can now work on/with. Check out some other commit, and you get some other set of files. The `git worktree add` command simply adds another area where you can check out a different commit, perhaps using a different branch name.

Comment: It's generally unwise, just from a human perspective, to add a worktree underneath your existing working tree. So `git worktree add src/new_branch` is going to mislead you; use `git worktree add ../new_branch` instead, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've quite understood the whole issue here, but `git worktree` is not meant to manage multiple branches in itself, at least not at this stage. `git worktree` provides you with one or multiple secondary working directories so you can simultaneously check out different revisions of a same repository.

This is useful for instance when you need to compare different versions of a library and need to compile them to do so. However, this won't affect the content of the branch itself.

Also, in order to be ABLE to do so, creating a new working repository implies the creation of another branch, because a given branch cannot be checked out at two different places under a same name : the problem here would be the same that distinguinshes `branch` and `remote/branch`: possible discrepancies that need to be resolved afterwards.